# Parse text file with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, text-parsing

I know normally you would use the `File.ReadAllLines`, but I'm trying to do it with an uploaded file.

Can I somehow put it into a temporary location?, or read it from memory?

I was able to get this working

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797576/c-file-upload-read-to-memory-and-use-as-text-file-is-there-a-better-way

Comment: What kind of parsing is needed, and why have you settled on LINQ?

Answer (score 4):

Is this a `string`, a `Stream`, or what? either way, you want a `TextReader` - the question is simply `StringReader` vs `StreamReader`. Once you have *that*, I would do something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(TextReader reader) {
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) yield return line;
}
```

then with whichever reader, I can either user:

```
foreach(var line in ReadLines(reader)) {
    // note: non-buffered - i.e. more memory-efficient
}
```

or:

```
string[] lines = ReadLines(reader).ToArray();
// note: buffered - all read into memory at once (less memory efficient)
```

i.e. if it is a `Stream` you are reading from:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream)) {
    foreach(var line in ReadLines(reader)) {
        // do something fun and interesting
    }
}
```